# Прочитать файл в k процессов

Tags: c++, linux

Интересует такой вопрос: как прочитать файл, представленный потоком(std::ifstream) используя k процессов с использованием fork()? Знаю как обработать его в k потоков, разделив файл(поток) на блоки кратные k потокам.

Comment: Можно просто в новом потоке заново открыть и прочитать.

Comment: Я бы рад потоки использовать, но по заданию нужно использовать только процессы(

Answer (score 1):

Нечто вроде:

```
int pid;
long offset;
long SegmetSize = ??; // Размер сегмента файла для одного процесса

// Мы в родительском процессе - открываем файл
FILE *f;
f = fopen(...);
if (f == NULL) ...

// Запускаем дочерние
for (j=0; j<k; j++) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        // Обрабатываем ошибку
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        // Мы в родительском процессе - продолжаем запуск
        continue;
    } else {
        // Мы в дочернем процессе - позиционируемся на нужный участок файла
        offset = j * SegmetSize;
        rc = fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET);
        // И начинаем обработку с этой точки
        while (...) {
            fread(..., f);
            // Что-то делаем
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А если файл представлен строками? Вернее это текстовый файл который нужно читать построчно?

Comment: @fat-complex Я думаю, можно решить эту проблему. Введём понятие "строка, заврешающая блок". Все процессы, кроме **последнего**, выполняют обработку до этой строки.  Все процессы, кроме **первого** после *fseek()*  ищут символ '\n' и начинают обработку после него. Обработав первую строку своего блока, заменяют её строкой  завершения блока. Если обрабатываемый файл портить нельзя, можно сделать разделяемый файлик, содержащий позиции начал обрабатываемых блоков в файле. Важно что бы процессы запускались от конца файла к началу.